# curl outputs Unicode codes instead of characters for Georgian

Tags: bash, shell, curl

curl "http://XYX...&" -d "text=ვაპირებ"
this command provides the following json output for Georgian word (ვაპირებ)

```
{"tokens":[{"word":"\u10D5\u10D0\u10DE\u10D8\u10E0\u10D4\u10D1","count":1,"id":0,"msa":[{"lemma":"\u10D3\u10D0\u00B7\u10DE\u10D8\u10E0\u10D4\u10D1[\u10D0]/\u10DE\u10D8\u10E0","features":"V Act Pres <S-DO> <S:Nom> <DO:Dat> S:1Sg DO:3 >PRED","rid":0}]}],"startCpos":[],"endCpos":[]}
```

The output is correct but represented in Unicode codes "\u10D5\u10D0\u10DE\u10D8\u10E0\u10D4\u10D1", not in Georgian characters. So, I have to convert them in addition.

```
echo -e "\u10D5\u10D0\u10DE\u10D8\u10E0\u10D4\u10D1" => ვაპირებ
```

Is it possible to have character base output for georgian by cUrl command directly?

Comment: I don't think it's curl that does that. I think it's the JSON encoder on the server side that serves the JSON response in that way. You'll just have to read the JSON in, perhaps using `jq`, and all should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

curl doesn't do this sort of escaping; rather, the site that you're calling must be doing that. (In JSON, `"\u10D5\u10D0\u10DE\u10D8\u10E0\u10D4\u10D1"` is equivalent to `"ვაპირებ"`. Apparently this site feels that the former representation is easier to work with.)

You might want to check the site's documentation to see if it supports the option of returning `"ვაპირებ"` instead of `"\u10D5\u10D0\u10DE\u10D8\u10E0\u10D4\u10D1"`. Of course, even if it does, it will still need to escape characters such as newlines and backslashes, so you'll still need to handle that.

I think your best bet is to use a tool that understands JSON to process this, instead of however you're processing it now. For example, [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) understands this notation; if I pipe your example through `jq .`, I get:

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "word": "ვაპირებ",
      "count": 1,
      "id": 0,
      "msa": [
        {
          "lemma": "და·პირებ[ა]/პირ",
          "features": "V Act Pres <S-DO> <S:Nom> <DO:Dat> S:1Sg DO:3 >PRED",
          "rid": 0
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "startCpos": [],
  "endCpos": []
}
```